# Downloading files using servlets

Tags: java, file, servlets, download

hi i have tried the following java codes which works fine if i use them as a java application but when i use the same code in my servlet page they dont work means  i am not able to download the files. Please suggest what changes should i do so that i can download the file using Servlets.

a.

```
    java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL("http://169.254.174.150:8084/WebApplication1/files/check.txt").openStream());
    File f1 = new File("D:\\a.txt");
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f1);
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    while (in.read(data, 0, 1024) >= 0) {
        bout.write(data);
    }
    bout.close();
    in.close();
}
```

b. http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2012/04/13/download-file-from-http-https-server-using-java/

Answer (score 0):

One of the older JavaBeat examples like the one you specified can be found [here](http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2007/10/10/file-upload-and-download-using-java/)

I found other solutions too but this seems to be the most comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, insetad of writing it to a file try wrting the data directly to the responce. Before writing data you will have to set the following parameters to the responce

```
        //byte[] filedata = ; intialize your file contents
        String filename = "a.txt";

        //      set the header information in the response.
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
        res.setContentType("application/x-unknown");
        ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(filedata);
        BufferedInputStream bufStream = new BufferedInputStream(byteStream);
        ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = res.getOutputStream();
        int data = bufStream.read();
        while (data != -1)
        {
            responseOutputStream.write(data);
            data = bufStream.read();
        }

        bufStream.close();
        responseOutputStream.close();
```

where res is a HttpServletResponse object. After this you can write data to responseOutputStream.